# Using .htaccess to redirect all requests to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm hosting a Laravel application on my server and have set up a subdomain to host it in my virtual host.

I have another subdomain on my server and after hours of playing around trying to set up an .htaccess file, I came up with the below which redirects all requests to `www.mysite.net/example` to my subdomain `example.mysite.net` (e.g `www.mysite.net/example/12345` goes to `example.mysite.net/12345`)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(mysite\.net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

I'm wanting to tweak this to work with Laravel, but it doesn't quite work the same considering Laravel is hosted out of the following path `mysite.net/laravel/public` rather than `mysite.net/example`.

How would I edit the above `.htaccess` to redirect all requests to `mysite.net/laravel/public` to `laravel.mysite.net`? I.e `mysite.net/laravel/public/12345` would redirect to `laravel.mysite.net/12345`

**Edit**
Here is the Virtual Host I have added through Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName laravel.mysite.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
        <Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
            Options -Indexes
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule as **your very first rule** inside `/var/www/laravel/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mysite\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /laravel/public/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://laravel.mysite.net/%1 [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect rule of htaccess to redirect any directory to a different domain. Use the below code:

```
Redirect 302 /laravel/public/ http://laravel.mysite.net/
```

Please let me know if it helps you out.

Comment: This won't carry over their request, though, like I need. Note, I need the request to be carried over to the subdomain e.g `mysite.net/laravel/public/this-is-an-example` to go to `laravel.mysite.net/this-is-an-example`

Comment: This carries the request to the required domain. I have tried this. Try this once and then let me know if any issue comes.